# What ports/protocols are used by Windows' "Computer Management"?

Tags: windows, networking, remote, port

I usually connect to other Windows computers on my network using **My Computer > [right click] > Manage** and then **Computer management > [right click] > Connect to another computer**.

I would like to know which ports/protocols are being used when I do this.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, this is handled with RPC on port 445.

Comment: I think it could also be done via the old NBT ports 137-139, if 445 wasn't a possibility for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Windows is using dynamic port allocation for some services e.g. Disk Management which is using RPC. Meaning if you want to open a port in your hardware firewall you need to open one of the default defined ports; fore more information see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851?wa=wsignin1.0 Meaning Microsoft finally uses one of these ports 49152 - 65535.